# WSO2 BAM Hardware requirements

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to define a production grade hardware specification for WSO2 BAM. My requirement is to bridge multiple data sources including plain text, SAP, excel sheets etc and pump the data to WSO2 datastore. The data volume and velocity is relatively low around 8 MB a day. Data variety is fixed.

Following is my current specification:

> #### Hardware infrastructure for server
>
> 1. AMD Opteron 8222 SE, 3GHz, dual core
> 2. RAM: 2 GB for JVM and 2GB for the OS
> 3. HDD: Minimum 10 GB free disk space
>
> #### Hardware infrastructure for MYSQL databases
>
> 1. 8 GB RAM
> 2. Quad-core Opteron
> 3. 1 TB Disk Volume

#### Questions

> 1. Should I host cassandra separately? How many nodes in a ring is reccommended?
> 2. Should I host the hive scripts separately? Is it possible to separate hadoop and hive out of WSO2 BAM server? Recommended settings?